# scss-lint errors out on @charset UTF-8 because of Front Matter

Tags: sass, jekyll, scss-lint

I am using Vim with [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) syntax checking plugin, configured to lint scss files with default sass and scss-lint linters.
Opening css/main.scss in a Jekyll project, scss-lint returns error:
`css/main.scss:5:1 [E] Syntax Error: Invalid CSS after "@charset "utf-8"": expected "{", was ";"`

Removing the charset declaration results in the same error on the next line down, and so on...
Remove the Front Matter block and scss-lint no longer reports the error, but Jekyll requires an empty Front Matter block at the head of a sass file to process it and import partials and output css.

How do I configure scss-lint to ignore the Front Matter block?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vim or syntastic.

Comment: Disagree. My goal is to lint files while editing in Vim. The charset error was blocking this. That solving the problem in Vim also frees up scss-lint from choking on the same error when used from the command line is incidental.

Comment: That `.scss-lint.yml` is a scss-lint configuration file that is not used by Syntastic or by Vim. Your issue is a scss-lint issue and your "fix" is a scss-lint fix. The fact that you are using Syntastic in Vim is completely orthogonal to the issue *and* to the fix.

Comment: Syntastic utilizes scss-lint as a default out-of-the-box.  
Don't confuse the answer for the question.  
The _problem_ is that on Scss files with Front Matter, Syntastic returns a syntax error that doesn't really exist. Editing the file will not "fix" the error. The _problem_ is inflated because this behavior is not clearly documented.  
Adding  ~/.scss-lint.yml is one possible solution. It doesn't change the original use-case.  
Another possible (untested) solution is adding `"let g:syntastic_scss_scss_lint_args = "preprocess_command: "sed '1{/^---$/{:a N;/---$/!ba;d}}'"` to .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Add a .scss-lint.yml config file in your user directory containing the following:

`preprocess_command: "sed '1{/^---$/{:a N;/---$/!ba;d}}'"`

scss-lint gem will look for a config file first in the current working directory, then in the user directory.

The `preprocess_command` intstructs scss-lint to run the text of the scss file through the sed command first.

The sed command [strips out the Front Matter block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222257/4127415); the file is then passed to scss-lint for error checking with the @charset declaration now on the first line.
If there is no Front Matter block between triple dashes `---` starting on the first line, the file is passed from sed to scss-lint as is.